# how we get current window access Without activity?

Tags: android

How we get current window access Without  activity? i have a
    service and i want to get current window screen object. any body
    know how we will get??

```
sysbrightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(cr,
android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);
lpnew.screenBrightness = sysbrightness;                     
win.setAttributes(lpnew);

Note: i have not any activity,just i have service and want to get
current window.
```

Comment: I think there is no way to get current window without access to activity. 99.99% sure..

Comment: Just to think the other way around: do you want an arbitrary background service access the current foreground activity, e.g. your browser while you are entering an online banking transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. Only activities can access `Window` objects.